# Does SQL caching statement results

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

In my hive query editor for example I have a query that has a lot of repeating statements:

```
select
    100 * (count(book_id) - count(case when column1 is null or TRIM(column1) !='' or column1="N/A" or column1="NA" then book_id else null end)/count(book_id)) as missing_cnt_column1,
    100 * (count(book_id) - count(case when column2 is null or TRIM(column2) !='' or column2="N/A" or column2="NA" then book_id else null end)/count(book_id)) as missing_cnt_column2
    from table book_info
```

This script calculates percentage of valid values per each column. Regarding this a have a couple questions: 
1) Would statement count(book_id) be cached or calculated each time? This is pretty crucial to me because columns amount > 200
2) Can I somehow improve performance of this query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is fine.  The SQL engine is not going to cache `count(bookid)`.  BUT, by far, the vast amount of work is in the aggregation and not in counting things up.  The query will only loop through the data once, but probably keep a separate value that gets incremented for each `count()`.  This has basically no effect on performance, because reading the data would typically be more important.

You can use `avg()` instead of `count()` and simplify the calculation:

```
select avg(case when column1 is null or trim(column1) <> '' or column1 = 'N/A' or column1 = 'NA'
                then 0.0
                else 100.0
           end) as missing_cnt_column1,
       avg(case when column2 is null or trim(column2) <> '' or column2 = 'N/A' or column2 = 'NA'
                then 0.0
                else 100.0
           end) as missing_cnt_column2
from table book_info;
```